# Coreos Systemd Unit File - keep the container running

Tags: coreos

I am running CoreOS Stable 776.4.0.

I want to keep a container running all the time. But I cannot get it to work. When I expect the container to restart when it is killed. But it does not. I got it working before. But I don't remember how I did it.

Please help me!

I kill it by `docker stop proxy`

`Restart=always` will continuously stop and start the container.

This is my systemd unit file.

```
[Unit]
Description=nginx reverse proxy
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=on-failure
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker stop proxy
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm proxy
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -d --name proxy -p 80:80 -v          
          /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro zhex900/nginx-proxy

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -d --name proxy -p 80:80 -v          
      /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro zhex900/nginx-proxy
```

You are passing the `-d` option to the docker client, which means "start the container in the background and return immediately".  Because the client exits, systemd interprets this as a failure and will attempt to restart the service.

The simplest solution is to remove the `-d` from the command line.

Another option is to *not* use systemd, and to simply start the container with `docker run --restart=always ...`, which will cause Docker to ensure that the container is running, even after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I asked a stupid question. The problem was I was running the container as a daemon. Remove `-d` solved the problem.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name proxy -p 80:80 \ 
           -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro zhex900/nginx-proxy
```